# Software Raid 1

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have 3 hard disks.
2 of them contains Data.
1 of them contain operatin system.
If I create mdadm raid for the 2 data hard disks and in the future, the opearting system hard disk might fail, will I loose my mdadm raid data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your data disks would still be OK, but to make things easier you might want to make sure you have a backup copy of your mdadm.conf (if your linux distro uses that file) somewhere besides your operating system hard drive.